# nvd3 tooltip decimal format

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to display line graph.

Having a little trouble in formatting the tooltip content

This is the line I'm using to format the y-axis text

```
chart1.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
```

But, it is only taking effect on the y-axis.
If there is a value like 44.123231, in y-axis, it will show up like 44.12, but in the tooltip, it is showing 44.00.
What could be the issue?
Is there a way in nvd3 to format tooltip text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `chart.tooltip.valueFormatter()` to specify a formatting function.

Look at this [example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Zc4DhgnM2uoFhi3MHsI) in script.js line 29.

Here is the [documentation](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#tooltip) for the tooltip component in VCD3.js

Comment: throws error like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueFormatter' of undefined`

Comment: Which version of nvd3.js are you using?

Comment: You should upgrade. v1.8.1 had some tooltip changes.

Comment: 1.8.1 is in alpha state.. not sure if it is stable enough.. 1.7.1 is the last stable release. is'nt it possible to do it in this version??

Comment: No [1.8.1](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/releases/tag/v1.8.1) it is not in alpha state, it is the current realease